# Allow the possibility of zooming in a WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

How can I implement a WKWebview allowing to zoom in and out what is shown ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you checked "Scales page to fit"

or Try implementing viewForZoomingInScrollView